# date on DataGridView not formatting as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I have a column that uses the DateTime format that was set in the column styles.

When a user enters a date, it's not formatting it to the style that it is set to. As a matter of fact, it isn't doing anything to the field. I put gibberish in there and it takes it.

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't it at least format the date or give an error for wrong date format?

Comment: Some code would be useful here... particularly your xaml.

Comment: I am using windows forms on this project. What do you want me to show you? Its all set in the styles of the datagridview.

Comment: I'm not doing anything in code for this column. I am asking about the functionality of the column formatted as datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling an event on the datagridview, getting the text input and validating whether it's a date or not. I used the event `CellEndEdit`, but choose yours as you like.

[image]

```
private void CheckCellValue(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        //my column index on the date is 0; modify yours as needed!
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex != dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        //check whether this can be parsed as a date.
        string enteredVal = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(enteredVal, out dt))
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doh, that's not a date: " + enteredVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great and I have added what you posted, Thank you. Question though, what's the point of making the format of the column a datetime column if it doesn't do anything, at least from what I can tell?

Comment: @Eroc: great question; I have no idea!

Comment: @Eroc: I think if you have a DateTime in the Cell's .Value property, the grid would display the value with time, since it uses .ToString. Setting a date format in the cell style enables you to specify what the formatted date should look like, and there you can omit the time placeholders.

Comment: I used your code but I keep getting the error date format exception! I can't type the date as dd-MM-yyyy only when I type it as MM-dd-yyyy it works! I need help with this, I have been struggling for hours

Comment: @amateurprogrammer You should probably open a new question on StackOverflow and illustrate your problem with a screenshot.